# How to enable cookie set Node to React on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, passport.js

```
              MERN stack.
```

I was told to switch my front end to Heroku since my backend on heroku wont set cookies.

Now I switched my front to heroku but its still not setting cookies.

I'm not sure how to trouble shoot this.

So I feel whats most important is understanding how to trouble shoot this, not only just the answer.

My backend Logs me in

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(customFields, (username, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ username: username })
      .then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
          console.log("No user");
          return done(null, false);
        } else {
          const isValid = validPassword(password, user.hash, user.salt);
          if (isValid) {
            console.log("Logged in");

            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            console.log("Wrong Password");
            return done(null, true);
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        done(err);
      });
  })
);
```

But then my Auth middleware sends the else statement because i get it logged on the front end.

```
module.exports.isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
    // res.status(200).json({ user: req.user, auth: true });
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({ auth: false, msg: "Here" });
  }
};
```

Google told me to switch around stuff with proxy? I'm not familiar with those key values at all, but i tried it, using trustProxy on the cookie session

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "zdfbdaf",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      cookie: { secure: true },
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  })
);
```

but that didn't work. I put

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
```

above it and it still didnt work, so i deleted it.

I've been trying to deploy this for a week now and still running into issues that seem so hard to figure out.

Heres my node app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const routes = require("./routes");
const isAuth = require("./routes/authMiddleware").isAuth;
const connection = require("./config/database");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
// app.use((req, res, next) => {
//   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
// });
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "http://2607:fb90:b6e0:a363:f89f:be4b:a976:9ed0:3001",
      "https://fullfrontend.herokuapp.com",
      "http://localhost:3001",
      "localhost:3001",
      "http://localhost:3000",
      "localhost:3000",
    ],
    credentials: true,
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  })
);

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: [
      "http://2607:fb90:b6e0:a363:f89f:be4b:a976:9ed0:3001",
      "https://fullfrontend.herokuapp.com/",
      "http://fullfrontend.herokuapp.com/",
      "http://localhost:3001",
      "localhost:3001",
    ],
    credentials: true,
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`Connected: ${socket.id}`);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(`Disconnected user: ${socket.id}`);
  });
  socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
    // const mes = {
    //   userid: data.sender,
    //   messages: [{ user: data.sender, message: data.message }],
    // };
    const mes = {
      user: data.sender,
      message: data.message,
    };

    User.updateOne(
      {
        _id: data.receiver,
        "chats.userid": data.sender,
      },
      { $push: { "chats.$.messages": mes } },
      {
        upsert: true,
      },
      (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log(result);
        } else {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    );
    // User.findOne(
    //   {
    //     _id: data.receiver,
    //     : data.sender,
    //   },
    //   (err, result) => {
    //     if (!err) {
    //       console.log(err);
    //     } else {
    //       console.log(result);
    //     }
    //   }
    // );

    // function (err, docs) {
    //   if (!err) {
    //     User.updateOne(
    //       { _id: data.receiver },
    //       { $push: { chats: mes } },

    //       function (err, result) {
    //         if (err) {
    //           console.log(err);
    //         } else {
    //           console.log(result);
    //         }
    //       }
    //     );
    //   } else {
    //     console.log(err);
    //   }
    // }
  });
});

const User = mongoose.models.User;

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);

// require("dotenv").config({ path: `.env` });

app.use(express.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const sessionStore = new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
  collection: "sessions",
});


app.use(
  session({
    secret: "zdfbdaf",
resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      cookie: { secure: true },
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  })
);

require("./config/passport");

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/", routes);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

I'm not following any tutorial, I went full Send on this as my first project and its definitely very hard.

I should add that locally this was working, everything was gravy.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the stack you are using, but I went through a cookie issue in the Heroku env: for me the problem was due to the domain to which I was setting the cookie, because it was "protected" by heroku, you can read more [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com).